# .gitignore para multi projetos - Visual Studio

Tags: git, github, versionamento

### Cenário

Tenho um projeto versionado no github, montei um arquivo **.gitignore** para tornar o projeto mais leve e não versionar arquivos desnecessariamente, porém não estou tendo sucesso. Notem que o meu arquivo **.gitignore** esta na raiz do projeto.

### Dúvida

Todos os arquivos que coloquei no .gitignore continuam versionando. Como faço para resolver ?

### Estrutura do Projeto

.\70-483
|-----.git
|-----\ManageProgramFlow
|------|____________\Weblank.ManageProgramFlow
|--------------------|____________________/.vs
|--------------------|____________________/IMAP
|--------------------|____________________/UsingAsyncAwait
|--------------------|____________________/UsingConcurrentCollections
|--------------------|____________________Weblank.ManageProgramFlow.sln
|-----.gitignore
|-----LICENSE.md
|--------README.md

### Parte do .gitignore

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Parte do Projeto no GitHub

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Link do projeto no github http://www.github.com/weblank/70-483*

Comment: Qual é a pergunta?

Comment: Todos os arquivos que coloquei no .gitignore continuam versionando. Como faço para resolver ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode remover o *cache* dos arquivos e dessa forma o *gitignore* irá começar a ignorar os arquivos que já foram *comitados*.

Como base, irei usar este projeto de teste:

[image: Projeto inicial do Git]

Para isso basta executar o comando abaixo:

```
git  rm -r  --cached   .
    └┬┘ └┬┘ └───┬───┘ └┬┘
     │   │      │      └─── Pasta ou arquivo que você deseja remover o cache
     │   │      └───────────── Desassociar e remover caminhos apenas do índice.
     │   └──────────────────── Recursividade (em caso de pasta)
     └──────────────────────── Remove arquivos da árvore de trabalho e do índice
```

Feito isso, teremos o resultado abaixo caso executemos `git status`

[image: Resultado após o código acima]

Agora precisamos *comitar* as alterações:

```
git commit -m "Atualiza cache do gitignore"
```

E agora teremos os arquivos que não foram ignorados, como *untracked files*.

[image: Resultado]